# TimeoutException from ServletHandler in Jetty 9.3 after changing server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jetty, jetty-9

My backend was running fine on AWS EC2 Linux machine with Jetty 9.3 (`jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612`) and Java 8 (`jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`). It is working with Android and iOS mobile app clients.

After moving the backend to a different EC2 machine, but with the exact same configuration (we have a script that installs and configures new servers) and the same backend software, suddenly it started randomly throwing `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms` messages to the log, it happens to 1%-3% of incoming requests.

Here's an example output of a request that was timed out from request.log -

```
10.17.13.5 - - [13/Jul/2015:09:55:38 +0000] "GET https://example.com/feed?queryparams=value HTTP/1.1" 200 95724 "-" "App/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 8.4; Scale/2.00)"
```

After 30 seconds it produced (3) TimeoutException messages in stderr.log -

```
2015-07-13 09:56:13.019:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp636718812-758: /feed
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:408)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:70)
        at net.bull.javamelody.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:83)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1848)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:447)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:45)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2242)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-13 09:56:13.020:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp636718812-758: https://example.com/feed?queryparams=values
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:408)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:70)
        at net.bull.javamelody.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:83)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1848)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:447)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:45)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2242)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-13 09:56:13.020:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp636718812-758: Could not send response error 500: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
```

There shouldn't be any difference between the two EC2 machines, why does the other throw these exceptions?

Comment: The server was trying to write a response back to the client, but the client failed to read anything in 30 seconds, so the server timed out the exchange and closed the connection.

Comment: Also, 1% to 3% idle timeout for mobile clients is *very low* rates of timeouts.  You are doing fantastic job if you manage to keep the rates that low.

Comment: Got ya, so no need to panic. I wonder why it wasn't in the logs previously...